# When should I implement my authentication scheme?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am definitely going to use an authentication scheme (Devise) with 3 roles: user, admin & sponsor. The question is: should I implement authentication right away or wait until I have my other models/views in place first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is usefull to do it as first, so you can easely integrate them in other models, eg. log that a user does something, you will also be able to set weather a user should have access to a specific controller.

Unless, you have a good reason to not do it...

Answer (score 0):

A rather unexpected question, but you can safely create your authentication routine right away. In any project i create, authentication is definitely one of the first things i code, most times using Sorcery instead of Devise.

Comment: This will be my second Rails project. In my first project, I used the 'roll your own' scheme from Railscasts. This time around, I want something a little more robust and modular. I've heard good things about Devise, but also that it can be a little too complex.

Comment: it can be messy if you need customizations. it would be way better to use sorcery if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it doesn't really matter, but why not do it earlier than later? It's pre-built, allows early testing (and testing it often), and allows access control needs to evolve organically rather than waiting until they all pile up and you have to do it all at once.